# Does SQL accounts lower security for MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2008

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 which we host some databases on. We currently use Windows Integration for authentication.

We are starting to need the support of authenticating scripts from ASP.NET and other applications. These applications need to use "script credentials" as they run without a user logged in. We are not really wanting to do this with intergrated Login as we do the adminstrators, we are looking at SQL authentication. Does doing this lower our security?

Comment: Seriously? Security is programming related.

Comment: Of course this is programming related. He needs to do this because he's now supporting ASP.NET. If he didn't ask, his developers would have to. Kudos to Phillip for getting out in front of the devs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does.

Use an NT service account that can be configured to only run on certain servers.
Also, you can apply any rights (such as login interactively) using group policy.

SQL logins, although you can use the AD group policy for passwords etc, are inherently more insecure

You don't have to make this account sysadmin on SQL Server

Edit:

Some reasons for insecurity at the system and solution level, not SQL Server.

1. Password must be in plain text somewhere (code, app.config, etc).
   For a service account running an IIS App Pool, it does not have to be.
2. No restrictions on what client machine you use. That is, the service account can be limited to app or web server.
3. You may still need NFTS or UNC rights somewhere: SQL logins can not deal with this.

Comment: What specifically causes it to be less secure?

Comment: Thanks! I would vote up but I can't yet. Need 15 rep so.. sorry.